# How to create a soap service which requires username/password in soap Header

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

Please let me clarify my requirement . Following are the related requirement which I know/learned  .

1. Adding ws-security header. (I did it using apache rampart. Authenticating using UsernameToken)
   http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jws4/
2. Container level security constraint to access web-service(i did using config required in web.xml)
   http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/container-authentication-with-jax-ws-tomcat/
3. Application level where username/password is bind as Http Request header.
   http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/

Above three ways I don't want. My requirement is to Add custom header element which takes username/password . For One of our client I came across this requirement . The part of their wsdl is following

```
<s:element name="AuthenticationHeader" type="tns:AuthenticationHeader" />
      <s:complexType name="AuthenticationHeader">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
        <s:anyAttribute />
      </s:complexType>
```

xmlns for prefix s=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

At client side I have consumed the service by providing above complex-type element in soap header

Now I want to know how to create a soap service which will accept soap-header as above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also I see something which could probably be better in the XSD provided. The complex type can be given a different name to the global element.

```
<s:element name="AuthenticationHeader" type="tns:AuthenticationHeaderType" />
      <s:complexType name="AuthenticationHeaderType">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
        <s:anyAttribute />
      </s:complexType>
```

Implementation goes as below if the xsd is as mentioned above

```
  AuthenticationHeader authenticationHeader = new AuthenticationHeader();
 AuthenticationHeaderType authenticationHeaderType = new AuthenticationHeaderType();
    authenticationHeaderType.setUsername("MyUsername");
    authenticationHeaderType.setPassword("MyPassword");

authenticationHeader.setAuthenticationHeader(authenticationHeaderType );
```

Attach the above authenticationHeader object along with webservice request object.

---

Your example would create the below classes based on the xsd I prepared from the chunk that you gave

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="AuthenticationHeader" type="AuthenticationHeader" />
      <xs:complexType name="AuthenticationHeader">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:anyAttribute />
      </xs:complexType>
      </xs:schema>
```

The classes generated are as below

**ObjectFactory.java**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


/**
 * This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * generated in the com.auth package. 
 * <p>An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically 
 * construct new instances of the Java representation 
 * for XML content. The Java representation of XML 
 * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
 * and classes representing the binding of schema 
 * type definitions, element declarations and model 
 * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are 
 * provided in this class.
 * 
 */
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _AuthenticationHeader_QNAME = new QName("", "AuthenticationHeader");

    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: com.auth
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link AuthenticationHeader }
     * 
     */
    public AuthenticationHeader createAuthenticationHeader() {
        return new AuthenticationHeader();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link AuthenticationHeader }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "AuthenticationHeader")
    public JAXBElement<AuthenticationHeader> createAuthenticationHeader(AuthenticationHeader value) {
        return new JAXBElement<AuthenticationHeader>(_AuthenticationHeader_QNAME, AuthenticationHeader.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

and **AuthenticationHeader.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


/**
 * <p>Java class for AuthenticationHeader complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="AuthenticationHeader">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="UserName" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="Password" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;anyAttribute/>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AuthenticationHeader", propOrder = {
    "userName",
    "password"
})
public class AuthenticationHeader {

    @XmlElement(name = "UserName")
    protected String userName;
    @XmlElement(name = "Password")
    protected String password;
    @XmlAnyAttribute
    private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();

    /**
     * Gets the value of the userName property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the userName property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setUserName(String value) {
        this.userName = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the password property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the password property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setPassword(String value) {
        this.password = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a map that contains attributes that aren't bound to any typed property on this class.
     * 
     * <p>
     * the map is keyed by the name of the attribute and 
     * the value is the string value of the attribute.
     * 
     * the map returned by this method is live, and you can add new attribute
     * by updating the map directly. Because of this design, there's no setter.
     * 
     * 
     * @return
     *     always non-null
     */
    public Map<QName, String> getOtherAttributes() {
        return otherAttributes;
    }

}
```

You can implement your code the below way

```
public class ImplementAuthentication {

    void authentication() {

        AuthenticationHeader authenticationHeader = new AuthenticationHeader();

        authenticationHeader.setPassword("MyPassword");
        authenticationHeader.setUserName("MyUsername");

        ObjectFactory obj = new ObjectFactory();

        obj.createAuthenticationHeader(authenticationHeader);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this class AuthenticationHeaderType  is it part of ws library ?

Comment: Hi, I see that you are using the same name for complex type and global element. Please try to generate the code for the above xsd and try to set the objects.

Comment: Please check the implementation. I hope things are clear now with your sample ?

Comment: Just one more thing . How to attach this to soap service header . I follow following approach in my impl class for overidden method              public String getHelloWorldAsObject(@WebParam (name="HelloObject") String name) {
  
  return "Name Passed : "+new HelloMessage(name).getName();
 }

Comment: Got it you already added that . just check. I will try that but I think this will help and I can go ahead

Comment: You would need to check your stub classes on how you can attach the authentication part to your soap request. I could probably tell you if I had a look at the complete XSD of yours but not with the sample you have shown. Please check if there is a request.setAuthenticationHeader method available in your SOAP request, if it is available you can set is as request.setAuthenticationHeader(authenticationHeader);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82183/discussion-between-abhishek-saxena-and-kalyan-chavali).